# select each item in a list c#

Tags: c#, list, loops, listbox

So basically I've got two classes, Cars and SecretCars.

```
class Cars
{
    public string First;
    public string Last;
    public string Number;

    public Cars(string first, string last , string number)
    {
        First = first;
        Last = last;
        Number = number;        
    }

    public Cars()
    {

    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
     return this.First + ", " + this.Last + ", " +  this.Number;
    }

}


class SecretCars : Contact
{
    public SecretCars (string first, string last , string number) : base(first, last , number)
    {
        First = first;
        Last = last;
        Number = number;
    }

    public SecretCars() : base()
    {}

    public override string ToString()
    {
 return this.First + ", " + this.Last + ", " + "Secret cars";
    }
}
```

In the Form1.cs Ive got a listbox1, a textBox1, a button1 and three more textBoxs(textbox2, textbox3, textbox4).

whatever you type in textBox1 prints in listBox1, what i want to do next is to print the three variables that i have (First, Last, Number) in the three textboxes that i have left (textbox2, textbox3, textbox4), each and every value.

I'm supposed to use the following code:

```
Cars selectCar =(Cars)listBox1.SelectedItem;

textBox2.Text = selectCar.First;
textBox3.Text = selectCar.Last;
textBox4.Text = selectCar.Number;
```

When selecting items Im gettins this error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Contact'.

So my question is how can I make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: No, it didnt work, but thanks.

Comment: What error were you facing while using it?

Answer (score 1):

you add string object to listbox,and want to cast string object to Cars object using Cars selectCar =(Cars)listBox1.SelectedItem; So throw System.InvalidCastException,maybe you need to add Cars object to listbox

Answer (score 1):

let say you enter the name of car in `textBox1` and you add that in the `listBox1' and this happens with no issues.

now what you are trying to do is to take the item(s) from listBox1 and convert that into an object of `(Cars)`. If you remember, you did not add an object of `Cars` class but just a string taken from `textBox1`. You should add the string to a property of the class `Cars` and then add the object of `Cars` in the `listBox1`.

I am just giving you an example of how you can do it.

```
Cars car = new Cars()
{
     Name=textBox1.Text,
     Last="some text",
     Number="some text"
}

listBox1.Items.Add(car);
listBox1.DataMember = "Name";


Cars selectCar =(Cars)listBox1.SelectedItem;

textBox2.Text = selectCar.First;
textBox3.Text = selectCar.Last;
textBox4.Text = selectCar.Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if you enter the text TN-12-1234 in textBox1 then you could split it and add it in the list box, like

```
string[] carStr = textBox1.Text.Split('-');
Cars selectedCar = new Cars() { First = carStr[0], Last = carStr[1], Number = carStr[2] };
listBox1.Items.Add(selectedCar);
```

If you do so, then only you can typecast the listBox item to Cars as like,

```
Cars selectCar = (Cars)listBox1.SelectedItem;

textBox2.Text = selectCar.First;
textBox3.Text = selectCar.Last;
textBox4.Text = selectCar.Number;
```

Hope this helps...